# In Android App, How to arrange "a block of two vertical TextViews" and "one ImageView" with android:layout_weight

Tags: android, xml, android-layout-weight

I am developing an Android App.

In xml, I would like to arrange "a block of two vertical TextViews" and "one ImageView" with android:layout_weight, and the value of the former is 2 and the one of the latter is 1.

My code is following. However it doesn't work.(forced termination)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:minHeight="100dp"
android:weightSum="3"
>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/article"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/articleTitle"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:minHeight="20dp"
    />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/articleAbstract"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    />

  </LinearLayout>

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your TextViews have no width. It is a required attribute.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/articleTitle"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="20dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/articleAbstract"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="80dp"
        />
```